# Getting an error due to an action name not being recognised

Tags: python

I'm new to Python. Trying to get the following code working:

```
class Portfolio:
    def __init__(self, balance={}):
        self.__balance = balance.copy()

    def initSym(self, sym):
        if not sym in self.__balance:
            self.__balance[sym] = 0

    def invest(self, amt, fx):
        initSym(fx)
        self.__balance[fx] += amt

    def divest(self, amt, fx):
        initSym(fx)
        self.__balance[fx] -= amt

    def getBalance(self, fx):
        initSym(fx)
        return self.__balance[fx]

    wallets = {'Paul':Portfolio({}),'Anne':Portfolio({'USD':200}),'John':Portfolio({'CHF':500,'GBP':11000})}

    wallets['Anne'].getBalance('CHF')
```

However this gives the error:

```
NameError: name 'initSym' is not defined
```

Comment: You're missing the stacktrace but looks like you're simply missing the `self` part before the method call.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you're used to C or Java, this might look weird to you, because you're trying to call a class's method from inside one of the class's other methods and it's not working.

Python is kind of weird in how it handles this. Each class method is really just a standalone method bound to the class, that takes *an instance of the class* as its first parameter. As a result, if you want to use one of the class's other methods from inside one of its methods, then instead of doing

```
initSym(fx)
```

you have to do

```
self.initSym(fx)
```

Comment: Yup, I'm a C# guy. Yeah passing that "self" around is a big difference alright. Thanks

Answer (score 2):

You need to call the method on a object of this class, here `self`

```
def getBalance(self, fx):
    self.initSym(fx)
    return self.__balance[fx]
```

Answer (score 1):

When methods are components of a class, you must qualify them with the name of the class instance (`class_instance.method`). When the reference is made from another method of the same class, you must qualify them with **self** (`self.method_name`):

```
class Portfolio:
    def __init__(self, balance={}):
        self.__balance = balance.copy()

    def initSym(self, sym):
        if not sym in self.__balance:
            self.__balance[sym] = 0

    def invest(self, amt, fx):
        self.initSym(fx)
        self.__balance[fx] += amt

    def divest(self, amt, fx):
        self.initSym(fx)
        self.__balance[fx] -= amt

    def getBalance(self, fx):
        self.initSym(fx)
        return self.__balance[fx]

    wallets = {'Paul':Portfolio({}),'Anne':Portfolio({'USD':200}),'John':Portfolio({'CHF':500,'GBP':11000})}

    wallets['Anne'].getBalance('CHF')
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to use `self.initSym`. Here is the modification to your code:

```
class Portfolio:
    def __init__(self, balance={}):
        self.__balance = balance.copy()

    def initSym(self, sym):
        if not sym in self.__balance:
            self.__balance[sym] = 0

    def invest(self, amt, fx):
        self.initSym(fx)
        self.__balance[fx] += amt

    def divest(self, amt, fx):
        self.initSym(fx)
        self.__balance[fx] -= amt

    def getBalance(self, fx):
        self.initSym(fx)
        return self.__balance[fx]

    wallets = {'Paul':Portfolio({}),'Anne':Portfolio({'USD':200}),'John':Portfolio({'CHF':500,'GBP':11000})}

    wallets['Anne'].getBalance('CHF')
```

[Here](https://micropyramid.com/blog/understand-self-and-__init__-method-in-python-class/) is an explanation about famous `self` argument.